# Why puppeteer animations runs *faster* than real-time?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I'm rendering animations with Puppeteer in AWS Lambda and I'm facing a strange behaviour:
Puppeteer runs faster than real-time.

My animation takes 4 seconds on a regular desktop Chrome. When run in AWS-Lambda-Puppeteer it takes a range between 1 second to 4 seconds, depending on the viewport size.

Completely counter-intuitive, **the bigger the viewport, the faster it runs**. All the other variables are kept the same (CPU, mem, code, ...)

As expected, the code always generates 25 screenshots per second (whatever the viewport size), so 100 frames in 4 seconds. This makes me think that the node js code runs correctly in real time.

Using a viewport of 300x200, the animation takes 4 seconds and all 100 frames contain the animation.

When I change to a viewport of 600x400, the animation plays faster and takes less than 2 seconds, so the first 50 frames have the animation and the last 50 frames are static with the last animation frame.

As I increase the viewport size, the speed increases up to less of a second.

**Does anybody know if there's an explanation and a solution for this?**

Additional notes:

I don't think it's a problem with my code, as it creates the frames as expected. It seems more a Puppeteer behaviour / setting.

By the way, I'm taking screenshots using the regular:

```
page.screenshot({
   omitBackground: true
});
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a code snippet? It is quite difficult to find the bug in your code if you do not provide any code.

Comment: Thanks Emil. I don't think it's a bug in the code. The screenshots are rendered correctly. I think it's more a Puppeteer behaviour, maybe a setting. I don't know